# how to save hyperlink button in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have a list of hyperlink button, created at runtime

```
public void SaveBookmark()
        {
            Button objButton = new Button();
            objButton.Content = "Delete";
            objButton.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            objButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Colors.Black));
            objButton.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush((Colors.Black));

            HyperlinkButton objhyperlinkbtn = new HyperlinkButton();
            objhyperlinkbtn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            objhyperlinkbtn.FontSize = 34;
            objhyperlinkbtn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Colors.Black));
            objhyperlinkbtn.Tag = Index;

            stackpanel.Children.Add(objhlbBookMark);
            stackpanel.Children.Add(objButton);

        }
```

I want to save it in isolated storage.
please help me to save it in isolated storage.
I want to give user to choose bookmark if user save a bookmark then hyperlink button save on the page to view list of bookmarks

Comment: Don't rally understand, why you want to save UI Elements to the isolated storage. Can you give us some more information here?

Comment: Actually I give user to choose bookmark
if user save a bookmark then hyperlink button save on the page to view list of bookmarks

Comment: @RizwanQureshi, there's no point of saving the UI control to isolatedStorage. I think, you should use xml serialization to save the properties of the current item to isolatedStorage. So, when you'll need to build a control with same properties on different page, you can just load properties from xml file.

Comment: +1 more suggestion you can save only info, about the page state or you can keep the control type on ISO (isolated storage). There is no point to store UI control.

Answer (score 0):

You can "save" button itself in your code (just leave as it is).

However, you'd want to save hyperlinks themselves. If you need readability (so you can open and read file, which contains hyperlinks, via "Windows Phone Power Tools"), then use [json](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/04/how-to-store-json-data-in-windows-phone-8.aspx) for writing file (sample and screenshots included). Otherwise, use [binary stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx) (sample included).

Answer (score 0):

Well if I am getting your point correctly then.
make a wrapper class first

```
 public class HypProperties
    {
     public string contentText{get;Set;}
    public double Height{get;Set;}
    public double Width{get;Set;}
//othere properties add according to requirements
    }
```

Now You can use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to save an object inside.
Sample-
To save -

```
HypProperties obj=new HypProperties (){contentText="",Height=height,Width=width};
if(!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("KeyName"))
{
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["KeyName"]=obj;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

To retrieve

```
if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("KeyName"))
        {
        HypProperties obj=IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["KeyName"] as HypProperties;
        }
```

But I would suggest you to  just store the properties of that hyperlink button. Saving a UI Element is not the correct way.

Comment: so please tell me how can I save all properties of a control in isolated storage