# How to save all properties of a control in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have a hyperlink button control & simply I want to save its properties to isolated storage so please help me to save and retrieve all properties of a control

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to save all properties manually. Button's style can be saved "automatically" in xaml style. The only thing you want to save is hyperlink itself.

If you're not using mvvm, you can save it as

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyButton1"] = MyButton1.Context;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

Get it in the same manner:

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains["MyButton1"])
    return IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyButton1"]
else 
    return null; // or String.Empty
```

If you need some more custom parameters (like color and style) - just save them to IsolatedStorageSettings in the same manner. If you need to save even more custom parameters, use [Json or Binary writer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19492929/1154733).