# set textblock of isolated storage

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage, textblock

I can save text file into the isolated storage, but how to add in the textblock such as *profile saved 1*, *profile saved 2*? to let it continue.

below is my textblock:

```
textBlock5.Text = "Profile 1 Name and Admin Saved";
```

I would like the *profile 1* to go to *profile 2* when the user saves the second record. Then from the third record onwards it will be multiple name and admin saved.

Isolated storage of a windows phone 7.1, while I have stored a text file into it. Profile 1 and 2 is the things i would like to show in the textBlock5.Text when user clicked on the save button. Trying to achieve when user click one time of the button, it shows "Profile 1 Name and Admin Saved", when user click the second time which second data is stored, is "Profile 2 Name and Admin Saved", and when user click the save button on the third or more times, it shows "Multiple Profile Name and Admin Saved".

```
 //get the storage for your app 
        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //define a StreamWriter
        StreamWriter writeFile;

        if (!store.DirectoryExists("SaveFolder"))
        {
            //Create a directory folder
            store.CreateDirectory("SaveFolder");
            //Create a new file and use a StreamWriter to the store a new file in the directory we just created
            writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, store));
        }
        else
        {
            //Create a new file and use a StreamWriter to the store a new file in the directory we just created
            writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", FileMode.Append, store));
        }


        StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
        str.Write(textBox1.Text);
        str.Write(",");
        str.Write(textBox2.Text);


        writeFile.WriteLine(str.ToString());

        writeFile.Close();

        textBlock5.Text = "Profile 1 Name and Admin Saved";
```

Comment: I think you might need to clarify your requirements. I really can't understand what you mean. What is 'isolated storage'? What are Profiles 1 and 2? What are you trying to achieve? Where is your current code? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: check out the updates !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own control if you want to save UIControls in IsolatedStorage (at least in windows phone). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490182/how-to-save-hyperlink-button-in-isolated-storage) should help you to get through the issue you are having.

So basically you create something like that

```
[DataContract]
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
     // your implementations here
     [DataMember]
     public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

for all controllers you need. The code above is not tested so it might not work, but I hope you get the idea.

**EDIT**

For each property you insert in the class, you must use the Attribute Flag [DataMember]. In this manner you can serialize in the IsolatedStorage all informations you need